# Excel add row, continue on

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a quoting workbook.
There are 8 Sheets with products on each one, QTY/DESCRIPTION/UNIT/TOTAL, we build a product selection on each sheet by putting the QTY of the item we need into col A.

I want to create a `Main` sheet that will pull the items on the other sheets only if the QTY is not 0. I created the basic formulas so that if the QTY is 0, the row is blank, and if not it fills in the appropriate data but here's where I'm stuck.

Basically I'd like the `Main` sheet to go through the formula as it does, but to keep moving down the table, then go to the next table (next sheet) and continue. I'd also like it to not have any empty rows. Is this possible?

Current code:

```
Sub delblankrows()

Dim s1 As Worksheet
Dim tmpR As Range
Dim rowcount As Long, colcount As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Boolean

Set s1 = Sheets("Complete")
Set tmpR = s1.UsedRange
rowcount = tmpR.Rows.Count
colcount = tmpR.Columns.Count

For i = rowcount To 1 Step -1
    k = 0
For j = 1 To colcount
    If tmpR.Value2(i, j) <> "" Then
        k = 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: This is not a "code for me" (or even a "code for my company who are too cheap to pay someone to do this") site.  Please at least start on the code yourself and then, when / if you get stuck with a specific problem, come back and ask a specific question that we can answer - we'll be more than happy to help you.

Comment: I understand and i've been trying to do it on my own. I've got the individual macros but I can't figure out how to put it all together. I just want some help, i don't all of it done for me.

Comment: If you have done some of the work, post the code you have come up with.  That way we can **help** you fix the issue you are having.  (The issue with not having any code in the question is that there are hundreds of ways to achieve any particular task, but only a few of them will be easily incorporated into your code.  If we can see what code you are writing, we can limit the suggestions to ones that will be useful to you.)

Comment: Here is what i have for the delete empty rows. But if i add an item i can't get it to and another row. I maybe should go about it a different way?

Comment: Please post that code into your question.  (Click the "edit" at the bottom-left of the question, and then paste the code in at an appropriate spot.)  It's (nearly) impossible to read when it is in comments, plus comments will sometimes be automatically deleted by cleanup routines.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is to pull in rows (cell values and not formulas) from other worksheets that have a non-blank or non-zero QTY (assumed to be in column "A"), then the following will do that.  But from your problem statement you may well be doing something in addition to that.  This code assumes that you have a header row on each worksheet and that the data starts in row 2.  It also assumes that you only have data in columns "A" to "D":

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddRowContinueOn()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, cws As Worksheet
  Dim cLRow As Integer, sLRow As Integer

  Set cws = Worksheets("Complete")
  cLRow = cws.Cells(cws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 1

  Dim i As Integer, val As Integer
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Complete" Then
      sLRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
      For i = 2 To sLRow
        val = CInt(ws.Cells(i, "A").Value)
        If val <> 0 Then
          cws.Range("A" & cLRow & ":D" & cLRow).Value = ws.Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Value
          cLRow = cLRow + 1
        End If
      Next
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This is working almost exactly as I was hoping. But I've been trying to make 2 minor tweaks that I hope are do-able. I have played with the code for a while but I can't get it working.
First, I'd like to the macro run automatically anytime any of the QTY cell's are changed.
Second, if the QTY is changed back to 0, is there a way to have the row deleted from the Sheet "Complete"?